# Nginx status=ok with chunked loading

Tags: nginx, download, status, chunked, access-log

I want to check if a download of a file is finished or cancelled, so i found out that nginx has the option

> $request_completion which will give OK or an empty status

I edited the access.log that way that it will log the status parameter.
This method is working well, but I am a little bit confused, what if the user connects multiple times to that file and load it with chunks? Is the status set to "OK" if the last byte was sent, or "knows" nginx if its a multiple request?

For example:

> The user connects 4 times to the same file.
>
> > First request: 0-499 bytes
> >     Second req.  : 500-999 bytes
> >     Third  req.  : 1000-1499 bytes
> >     Fourth req.  : 1500-1623 bytes (End of the file)

Now the last request finished first, will nginx set the Status to "OK", or will it what until the 3 other requests will also finish?
If this is the case, who can I find out if all opened connections are closed?

Comment: What is `status=OK`?

Comment: $status is the response status from nginx
[nginx log format](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format)

Comment: It will not be `OK`. It's HTTP status code, so it will be `200`/`206`/`404`/etc.

Comment: For nginx these four requests are completely unrelated.

Comment: Sorry, "ok" comes from $request_completion, my fault, will correct
 it
If it's completely unrelated, who can i figure out if all active connections for a file have been closed?

Comment: Anyway, nginx process requests as completely unrelated to each other. You need some other way to tell if someone downloaded files in several requests

Comment: Ok thanks, good to know. I will going to think how i can handle that Problem.

Comment: @mjx649 I think you might be looking for post_action http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#post_action